# Capture a video of 10 seconds length and upload it to server using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, video, asihttprequest, video-capture

I need to capture a video which will be maximum length of 10 seconds, and also need to upload it to server using `ASIHttpRequest`,

how do I do that?

Comment: `Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)` - Written at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the videoMaximumDuration property of image picker for this.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes  = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


    imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the duration of the video by using this

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:selectedVideoUrl];
CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
```

You can upload it to server using

```
//server url to upload 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
//give your file path here and key
[request addFile:file_path forKey:@""];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

//successful uploaded
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
}
//when failed
- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
  NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)mediaDict {


       NSString *type = [mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

       if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
           [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { // movie != video
           NSURL *url = [mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
           NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
           // UPLOAD THIS DATA because you must convert  video file to NSData. and must take Post method.
       }
       return nil;
     }
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.